# Different versions of Node - Learning Angular 2

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

Some people may find this question duplicate but let me say I am a beginner to Angular 2, NPM and Node and finding it difficult even to setup the environment. Don't really know how difficult it will get once i start doing something with Angular 2.

I have started following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181888/Angular-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-API-Part) example but ended up with hundred and hundred of errors which were explained like mismatch of the different package version etc by different people at Stack Over Flow so abandoned that exercise and get back to the setting up NPM and Node etc. and started following [link2](http://www.ryadel.com/en/visual-studio-2015-update-nodejs-andor-npm-latest-version/).

By following the link2 I have installed the NPM with some warning and errors. A screen shot is as follow

[image: NPM installation result where it is showing Node version 5.4.1]

Moving further to the second step of NodeJS installation, I downloaded the recommended version (6.11.4) from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/) and installed on its default location (C:\Program Files\nodejs). A screen shot is as follow

[image]

After above installations, I am wondering why I have different versions of Nodejs as it can be seen from screen shot 1 and 2. Although, both paths pointing to different locations but I followed as in link2. Am i missing something here or this is how it should be? OH! forgot to mention, I have set up the External Web Tools to the C:\Program Files\nodejs location in my Visual Studio (2015).

VS 2015 External Web Tools settings screen shot is as follow

[image]

I am completely lost here and don't really want to waste hours start following any of the angular 2 practice example and then finding out there are errors again because of the older version of packages etc. Also, don't really understand why it is such a pain to set up the environment for Angular 2?

Comment: You'll find Visual Studio will have its own version of Node.js and Typescript.  You can fix the node.js issue by changing the path to node and npm (in VS "External Web Tools", then prioritize the path to Node.js and npm).  You can fix the Typescript issue by installing the latest VS extension for Typescript (you may have to look outside of Visual Studio for the Typescript extension - make sure its from Microsoft).  If you want to find out which version of Typescript you have installed, go to Visual Studio > Help > About Visual Studio.

Comment: I did install the latest version of Typescript when I was following the link1 Code Project example.

Comment: Make sure its the same version as "tsc -v" outside of Visual Studio just to make sure that the Typescript node package installed using "npm install" is the same version that Visual Studio is using.

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs> and in Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External> both have tsc -v,  1.0.3.0

Comment: hm, that is really out-of-date... because its so old, I suspect your compilation issues is related to typescript. Check package.json of the angular example that you're using and see which version of typescript it should be using.  You can update typescript to the latest version globally: npm install -g typescript (should be v2.5.2).

Comment: You are absolutely right! Example is using the 1.0.3.0 version. How should i update my Typescript? Download and install the latest version and then point the package.json version to the latest?

Comment: Yes, install the latest Typescript extension for visual studio (v2.5.3): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True.  Make sure this matches your typescript installed globally (npm install -g typescript).  Also, I suggest abandoning that example in favor of a more recent Angular4 tutorial, typescript 1.0 is really old, and a lot has changed :)

Comment: You mean Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External and the global npm install -g typescript should have the same version i-e 2.5.3 (latest).

Comment: Yes, that's right. As of now, 2.5.3 is the latest version. For the VS2015 typescript version, go to Visual Studio > Help > About Visual Studio (scroll to bottom)

Comment: I have installed the latest version but Web => External still showing me the version 1.0.3.0 while npm install -g typescript has successfully installed the latest version i-e 2.5.3 at global loation. is there any command to upgrade the Web => External version of typescript?

Comment: This is a common problem - you may have Microsoft SDKs installed which has Typescript 1.0... I believe you need VS2015 update 3.  Make sure to restart VS2015 after you've installed the extension or prioritize paths to fix this... its been a while, so not sure.  Follow these instructions from Angular: https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015#!#create-project

Comment: To my wonder, "About Microsoft Visual Studio" is showing the version 2.5.3.0 while on command prompt Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External it is 1.0.3.0. Also, yes i do have Microsoft SDK kit installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156096/discussion-between-pixelbits-and-learning-curve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting up your VS2015 environment correctly, follow the quickstart guide from Angular:

https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems. The issue is that Visual Studio has installed it's own version of node that it comes packaged with, and set the environmental variables to point it it's old version.

Try checking the environmental variable "Path" for any reference to Node.

If you're trying to do all this with Visual Studio as your IDE, try going to `tools > options` and `Projects and solutions -> External Web Tools` and adding the route to your newer manually installed node:

[image]

If you're not using Visual Studio (say, you're using Visual Stuido Code, which is different) try not using the Visual Studio directories to contain your project.

Edit: See you've done this already - can you show a screenshot? Have you restarted VS? What order are they in (it is important). Try moving the `$(PATH)` up to the top too. The nodejs should be added to your PATH variable.

> Also, don't really understand why it is such a pain to set up the environment for Angular 2?

It's the reality of trying to get all these tools to work together. Angular is just as bad as anything else really. If you wanted to do any kind of complex javascript development you'd need to install Node and go through all this.

Once you get over the hill and start being able to *do* things it gets better! Keep at it.

Comment: I am using VS 2015 and have already set the path in IDE as explained in my original post.

Comment: Sorry missed it, added edit. Can you post a screenshot? The order is important.

Comment: I have edited my original post. External Web Tools setting screenshot is added.

Comment: That's very strange that it doesn't work. Did you check your PATH (and try moving it to the top)? What do other directories (C:\SomeProjectsFolder) have for `node -v`? I found my life got a lot easier when I stopped using Visual Studio and started using VS Code for angular development.